# How Should I Store/Display My Date/Time Field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

I know there's a ton of questions around date/time storage and formatting, but I'm struggling to get the right approach. My app is a Node.js app with Express using mongoose with a MongoDB backend. I'm using moment.js to format my date/times.

The schema in question looks like:

```
const stateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  changed: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
  }
});
```

Based on the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/), I was expecting the date to be stored in UTC by default, but instead I see this:

```
changed: 2018-08-15 17:26:14.499
```

I'm displaying the date/time with something like (pug):

```
p= `Changed: ${moment(state.changed).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}`
```

On localhost, the app shows "August 15th 2018, 5:26:14 pm" but on the hosted Heroku app I get "August 15th 2018, 10:26:14 pm." I am expecting "August 15th 2018, 5:26:14 pm" because I'm opening the Heroku app in the same timezone, but it looks like it's giving me the server timezone.

What should I do to make sure the date/time shows up in the client's local timezone?

Comment: It's written in the doc you provided that you can save the offset as well and then convert to your local time accordingly.

Comment: Unless I'm reading it wrong, that doc says the date is stored as UTC and displayed in client local timezone by default, and you only need getTimezoneOffset() if you want to display it in the original time zone, which I don't. What am I missing?

Comment: Server-side rendering is happening here because the entire HTML is created on the server and then sent to the browser (the client). You have to get the timezone of client with help of a script and then convert UTC to that timezone.

Comment: Makes sense. How to get the client's timezone in a Node.js app then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the answer. It gives me the wrong time on localhost, but should be the correct time on the hosted app, no matter where I am.

Add offset to schema:

```
const stateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  changed: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
  },
  offset: {
    type: Number,
    default: new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
  }
});
```

Then subtract the offset when displaying:

```
p= `Changed: ${h.moment(state.changed.getTime() - (state.offset * 60000)).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}`
```